# How to link html, php pages to slim routes

Tags: php, html, api, rest, slim

I really want to make a rest api project but i can't understand how.
For now i have all the html css and php pages, i have a functional php app with database.
Also i have slim routes tested with Postman and all works(return Json). My question is: how do i link all that parts to make a functional rest api aplication?

My routes looks like that:

```
$app->get('/api/users', function( Request $request, Response $response){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";

    try {

        $db = new db();

        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query( $sql );
        $users = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        $db = null; // clear db object

        echo json_encode( $users );

    } catch( PDOException $e ) {

        echo '{"error": {"msg": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}';

    }

});
```

I read about several options but i can't understand how all this works. How i get data from forms for example and pass to route and route output the result that i want using data from forms.
Can you suggest me a simple way to do that and all the framework that i need?

Comment: what is your error ? if $users is really not empty try "return" than "echo"

Comment: I don't have an arror, i just want to find out how to link that route for example to php or html pages. That route return json file, not a page for a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a UI (user interface) then you need to build a front-end application - written in Javascript assuming it would be a web front-end (perhaps using one of the popular frameworks such as React or Angular) - which can then make calls to your API via AJAX requests to get data to populate the screens etc. Or you could make almost any other type of application to talk to it

Your API is the backend...it can support having lots of different types of application calling it potentially (e.g. web app, mobile app, desktop app, automated service, IoT device etc) - that's the beauty of separating the core, shared functionality and logic of your system into an API, away from the potential different client-side experiences you might decide to create.